# compare the dates and create the missing record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm facing a problem in finding the solution for the below scenario.
I have 3 records for a product which has the following start_date and end_date.

```
Case:1
record1: 03-10-2012 and 30-10-2012
record2: 03-10-2012 and 10-10-2012
record3: 11-10-2012 and 20-10-2012

Case:2
record1: 03-10-2012 and 30-10-2012
record2: 11-10-2012 and 20-10-2012
record3: 21-10-2012 and 30-10-2012

Case:3
record1: 03-10-2012 and 30-10-2012
record2: 03-10-2012 and 10-10-2012
record3: 21-10-2012 and 30-10-2012
```

In all the above cases I need to create the 4th record with the missing dates(For example in case1, I need a record from 21st to 30th) and would like to delete the record1 which is no longer required if I have the record with the missing dates.

Is there any way to do everything in one go?
I have tried doing it using the case command but no luck.

This is what I have written.

```
select MIN(end_date) AS min_end_date, MIN(start_date) AS min_start_date, 
    CASE WHEN MIN(start_date) <= MIN(end_date) AND MIN(start_date) > DATE '#{start_date}' THEN DATE_SUB(MIN(start_date), INTERVAL 1 day)
        ELSE MIN(end_date)
        END AS min_date
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...you could do the following:

```
remainders=(record1.start_date..record1.end_date).to_a - (record2.start_date..record2.end_date).to_a - (record3.start_date..record3.end_date).to_a
```

Afterwards you can do a safety check –or let it be, if you trust your data-

```
if (remainders.first..remainders.last).to_a == remainders
  record4.start_date = remainders.first
  record4.end_date = remainders.last
  record1.destroy
else
  raise
end
```

Comment: You might want to consider to wrap this in a transaction, e.g. if this is a one-time conversion.

Comment: No problem :-) If thats the answer you were looking for, I wouldn't mind if you checked it as the answer ;-)